# How to migrate read file from ftp flow to mule 4.1.4 Kernel version?

Tags: migration, kernel, mule, transformer-model, mule-flow

people! I am migrating to mule 4 Kernel version.

I'm stuck in this moment: requirement is to read file from FTP and then process it. In old version it was like a few components: 
1. quartz, 
2. transformer 
3. transformer 
4. queue

Can somebody help me to migrate it to mule 4 kernel?

How to do this? How to put file content as string into queue like it was in older version? It would be nice if we could talking about Mule Kernel version. I'm new member of this community and of Mule developers, to pls dont hate me.

In next step I'm gonna split this file (splitter) but I know in Kernel there is not splitters anymore, so I have to use for each, right?

Now I've got 
1. http listener (but it should be job. For my own tests It is http listener, I'm gonna to change this). 
2. FTP read with FTP connector 
3. ????

```
<flow> 
         <quartz 
               with cronExpression 
               and with conector to FTP>
          </quartz>
          <gzip-uncompress-transformer encoding="UTF-8"></gzip-uncompress-transformer>  
          <byte-array-to-string-transformer encoding="UTF-8"></byte-array-to-string-transformer>  
          <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="xxx" ></jms:outbound-endpoint>  
      </flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to read the migration guide and try to migrate each component to its equivalent in Mule 4: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/index-migration

For the example you mentioned it should very straightforward.

Quar

- tz: it was already deprecated in Mule 3 by the Poll element. Its
  replacement in Mule 4 is the Scheduler:
  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-core-poll
- FTP:
  there is a new FTP connector, which works in operations rather than
  inbound/output:
  https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-connectors-ftp-sftp
- gzip uncompress: this isn't mentioned in the migration guide but just a search shows that there is a replacement: https://docs.mulesoft.com/connectors/compression/compression-module#gzip-decompressor-strategy
- jms outbount: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-connectors-jms#SendingMessages
- : this kind of low level transformation is usually not needed anymore in Mule 4. (https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.2/migration-core)

Most of the information is already in the documentation.

Another suggestion is try to use the latest available version of Mule and connectors.